# Vue pass pre-determined value

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a form that I want the user to edit. Meaning that the value from the database should be present in the input field and the user can change it or not change it. I'm currently trying to do it like this.

```
 <div v-for="(property, propIndex) in properties" :key="propIndex">
   <input type="text" v-model="property_name[propIndex]" value="{{property.property_name}}"><br>
</div>
```

But everything breaks and I get a blank screen. How do I pass in a pre-determined value in Vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `v-model` to `property.property_name`, this way it will have its initial value and will update the list on change:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    properties: [
      { property_name:'property_name1' }, { property_name:'property_name2' },
    ]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{properties}}
  <div v-for="(property, propIndex) in properties" :key="propIndex">
    <input type="text" v-model="property.property_name"><br>
  </div>
</div>
```